# WatchOS2 Health Kit - Adding to Activity Move Ring

Tags: objective-c, watchos-2, healthkit

I am creating a little testing app with HealthKit trying to include manual workouts on the Activity Circles.

My code is below the screenshot.

From the image below the 178 Cal Other Workout and the 83 Cal Rower were created from the Watch Workout App both are showing the green circle next to them (To indicate they are included in the circle).

The 3rd Workout the "188 Cal Outdoor Run" was created from my testing app but shows the App Icon and no green ring and is not included in the circles?

Note: Until updating to iOS 9.0.1 there was NOTHING where the app icon is now placed.

[image]

Code:

```
HKQuantity *kCal = [HKQuantity quantityWithUnit:[HKUnit kilocalorieUnit] doubleValue:188];
HKQuantity *disance = [HKQuantity quantityWithUnit:[HKUnit meterUnit] doubleValue:2000];

NSDate *startDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-3600];
NSDate *endDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-60];

HKWorkout *workout = [HKWorkout workoutWithActivityType:HKWorkoutActivityTypeRunning startDate:startDate endDate:endDate duration:3540 totalEnergyBurned:kCal totalDistance:disance metadata:nil];

[self.healthStore saveObject:workout withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    HKQuantity *heartRateForInterval = [HKQuantity quantityWithUnit:[HKUnit unitFromString:@"count/min"] doubleValue:95.0];

    HKQuantitySample *heartRateForIntervalSample = [HKQuantitySample quantitySampleWithType:[HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate]
                                    quantity:heartRateForInterval
                                   startDate:startDate
                                     endDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:60 sinceDate:startDate]];

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    if(!success)
    {
        [self.statusLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"saveObject: %@", error.localizedDescription]];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.statusLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Success"]];

        [self.healthStore addSamples:@[heartRateForIntervalSample] toWorkout:workout completion:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {

            if(success) {
                [weakSelf.statusLabel setText:@"Saved - Added Sample"];
            } else {
                [weakSelf.statusLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"addSamples: %@", error.localizedDescription]];
            }

        }];
    }

}];
```

Comment: Does your app save the workout on the watch or on the companion?

Comment: @Allan: I save the workout on the Watch.

Comment: Last night I added real heart rate samples from HKWorkoutSession and still didn't add to the Move Ring. I thought I would try this incase my Heart Rate Sample data wasn't accurate enough.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you provide the code that got you a green ring for the Other and Rower workouts?

Comment: The Other and Rower workouts were created by the built-in Workout app.

Comment: Got you - thanks for the reply. I misread the "Watch Workout App" as being your test app. I'll stop attempting this now!

Comment: @jodm on 9.0.2, I can't even get workouts to show up in the Activity app (at all). Have tried saving from both iPhone and Watch; also tried the Strava app. Can you confirm that this still works?

Answer (score 0):

It is not sufficient to save a workout with a non-zero `HKQuantity` for the totalEnergyBurned property.  Your app must also add associated active energy burn samples to the workout in order to be counted towards the Move ring.  See the `HKHealthStore` documentation for the [addSamples:toWorkout:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKHealthStore_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/HKHealthStore/addSamples:toWorkout:completion:) method.  Ideally, the active energy samples should be fine-grained so that the user can see changes in intensity over the course of their workout.

Comment: Does that add to the move ring (which is pink) or the exercise ring (which is green)? The OP mentioned move ring in their title but their screenshot shows the exercise ring. I'm working on adding workouts manually to increase the exercise (green) ring without luck - does this work for pink, green, or both?

Comment: Just gave it a try and can confirm that you can add to the move (pink) ring by adding samples of `HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned` to a `HKWorkout` - can't seem to find a way to extend the exercise (green) ring though...

Comment: There is no way to make your app's workouts contribute directly to the Exercise ring.

Comment: @Allan Is this credited no matter what so long as your heart rate reaches the threshold?

Comment: @Allan Still there is no way to contribute directly to the Exercise ring?

Comment: @pradipsutariya There is still no way directly influence the Exercise ring from an app on watchOS besides recording a live workout. A workout saved by an app on iOS will contribute to all the rings for watch users, though.